# Set single password for ALL Subscribers & Keep the user logged in - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, registration

I'm using the following code to set a single password for all subscriber roles. The issue I'm facing is that it works - but once the subscriber is logged in, and decides to move to a different page (or even reload the page), the user gets logged out immediately.

```
$subscribers = get_users('role=subscriber');
foreach ($subscribers as $user) {
wp_set_password('Password123', $user->ID);
}
```

Comment: Where & when does the code you have shown execute? Was the user logged in to the system _before_ you changed the password? What happens after the log in again now using the new password, do they stay logged in then?

Comment: @CBroe The code executes every time, the subscriber sign-ups on the site. So, the code is changing assigning the password, to every new subscriber role on sign up.

Comment: So how exactly is this limited to _new_ subscribers? `get_users('role=subscriber')` doesn't look like it does that.

Comment: I'm ok with it being not limited to new subscribers, I'm not well versed in PHP, just know some very basics. I'll be grateful for any assistance, to get it working, so the user doesn't automatically get logged out. @CBroe